# How to delete the parent entity and its children with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following case OneToMany:

A document can have multiple versions

**DocumentoImpl**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = VersionDocumento.Properties.DOCUMENTO, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<VersionDocumentoImpl> versiones;
```

**VersionDocumentoImpl**

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = DocumentoImpl.Columns.ID_DOCUMENTO, referencedColumnName = DocumentoImpl.Columns.ID_DOCUMENTO, nullable = false)
    private DocumentoImpl documento;
```

**DocumentoServiceImpl**

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(Long idDocumento) {
        this.documentoRepository.delete(idDocumento);
    }
```

When I run the delete web service, it returns a code 200 but does not delete the document and its versions.

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: what's the source code of the service? what's the source code of the controller? It's not clear how you call this delete method in DocumentoServiceImpl. Plus it's also unclear what is `DocumentoServiceImpl`? Is it a `CrudRepository`? If yes then you need to use `deleteById` and not `delete`